# Не могу создать профиль юзера DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель Profile

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=30)
    patronymic = models.CharField("Отчество", max_length=30)
    kind = models.CharField("Клиент или специалист", max_length=20, choices=KIND_CHOICES)
    regions = models.CharField("Регионы", max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField("Телефон", max_length=15)
```

Профиль создаётся изначально как только создан юзер (т.е user уже связан с этим профилем, но профиль пустой)  (сигнал)
Мне нужно принять POST запрос и **наполнить** пустой профиль

Сделал сериализатор вот таким:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'user', 'name', 'surname', 
            'patronymic', 'kind', 'regions', 
            'phone', 'company', 'categories'
        ]
```

**views**:

```py
class ProfileCreate(generics.GenericAPIView):
    # Наполнение профиля юзера

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.profile = serializer.save()
            return Response(ProfileSerializer(user.profile))
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Вылетает ошибка:
**IntegrityError at /api/profile/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: app_profile.user_id**

Помогите решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша модель `Profile` не получает данных для поля `user`.

Один из вариантов - переопределить метод `create`, в ваш `ProfileSerializer`:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user,
                                 **validated_data)
        return profile
```